# How to get the title of the last PR pushed to main branch?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a workflow in GitHub Actions to build my code. This workflow is triggered on pushes and pull requests to my main branch

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, I haven't specified a "run-name" so it gets created automatically.

This is how it looks in the Actions tab:

[image]

The one below is the pull request. The name for that run **"API-0000 Some Other Name"** was the title of the PR.

When I push the PR to main, the Action runs again. This time, the name of the run was set to **"API-0000 Some Other Name"** plus the PR number **(#206)**

I want to add the `github.run_id` to these automatically generated run-names, and for that I need to specify a custom run-name.

I know how to get the PR title when building the PR, but I cannot find how to get that same value when building the main branch after pushing the PR.

This is what I have so far:

```
run-name: ${{ github.event.pull_request.title || ***GET PR TITLE FROM PUSH TO MASTER*** }} (Run-Id ${{ github.run_id }})
```

With this logic, when I open a PR, the name of the run gets set to **"API-0000 Some Other Name (Run-Id 1234567890)"** which is what I want.

When I push the PR to main and the workflow runs for that branch, `github.event.pull_request.title` becomes null and that's when I need to get that value from somewhere else, so that the run name continues to be **"API-0000 Some Other Name (Run-Id 1234567890)"** (actually, it would be a different Run-Id)

Because when I don't set a custom run-name, GitHub automatically uses the last PR title to build the main branch, my assumption is that the value is available. I just can't find how to get it.

Does anyone know how can I get the title of last PR pushed to master?

Comment: Don't you just want the name of the commit? That's the default title.

Comment: Yes, that's part of what I want and that's the default title. But I want to add more information to it (the Run-Id) so I have to explicitly set the whole run-name.

Comment: The point being the triggering event isn't a pull request, so the PR title isn't accessible, it's a commit, so the commit message _is_ accessible.

Comment: The action is used both for pull request and push events. I do need the PR title when the action runs for a PR. That part works fine.

Now, when the action runs for a push, I'm trying to find how to get the exact value as the PR title, which as you correctly pointed is not available. Using "github.event.head_commit.message" doesn't work as it returns the names of all the commits (I squash them before merging).

The default value for the run-name contains just the value of PR title ALSO when pushing to the main branch so I'm trying to find out which is the property used by GitHub by default

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging, it turns up what I want do do can't be done.

Upon inspecting the github context for "push" events, the only information available is in github.event.head_commit

Within this object, there is the property github.event.head_commit.message but that is the commit message, and not the Pull Request title. Actually, it's a concatenation of the PR title plus the commit message.

As the run-name is set before any job runs, I cannot run any action to split the string and get the part I want.

What lead me to believe it can be done is that when I don't explicitly set a run-name, GitHub automatically defaults it to just the PR title for "push" events.